# Get row number of UITableview with multiple sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView`, with multiple sections in it, and each section has multiple rows. I want to get the row number of selected cell with respect to the entire table and not the section only.

example:

1. I have two sections in the `UITableView`, section 1 has 3 rows and section 2 has 5 rows.
2. When I select sections 2's 2nd row, I should get the 5 as the row number in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, rather than getting 2 as the row number (which is with respect to the section).

I tried to get the row number myself by doing the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);

int theRow =  indexPath.row;

NSLog(@"%d",theRow);
}
```

I was thinking of storing the row number in an `int`variable, and then add row numbers to it myself, but the code crashes when trying to store  `indexpath.row` in `theRow` .

Please help. Thank you

Comment: You own the model, so you tell the table view how many rows it has. Just add everything up.

Comment: @Wain Can you explain a little more? I am sorry, but I didn't get what you said.

Comment: @SHA: Can you explain why you want to work with an "absolute" row number instead of a "section relative" row number?

Comment: @MartinR: To get a value from that (abosulte row number) index of an Array.

Comment: @SHA: OK, but you might also consider to use a *nested array* (with the section number as first index and the row number as second index) as data source.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
NSInteger rowNumber = 0;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
    rowNumber += [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}

rowNumber += indexPath.row;
```

Comment: ... or `[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]` - the table view caches the value returned from the data source.

Comment: You are counting the number of rows.  Is that what they want?

Comment: @Wain, Thank you so much. That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a cleaner implementation of this concept in Swift:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    var rowNumber = indexPath.row
    for i in 0..<indexPath.section {
        rowNumber += self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(i)
    }

    // Do whatever here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. just an issue as a renamed edit: numberOfRowsInSection(i) renamed as numberOfRows(inSection: i).

Answer (score 9):

Here is a Swift adaption of the above answer by Wain

```
class func returnPositionForThisIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath, insideThisTable theTable:UITableView)->Int{

    var i = 0
    var rowCount = 0

    while i < indexPath.section {

        rowCount += theTable.numberOfRowsInSection(i)

        i++
    }

    rowCount += indexPath.row

    return rowCount
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a big data set and the previous answers using for loops was causing performance issues for me in the lower sections. I ended up doing the calculating beforehand and sped things up a bit.

```
private var sectionCounts = [Int:Int]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let number = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    if section == 0 {
        sectionCounts[section] = number
    } else {
        sectionCounts[section] = number + (sectionCounts[section-1] ?? 0)
    }
    return number
}

func totalRowIndex(forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return indexPath.row
    } else {
        return (sectionCounts[indexPath.section-1] ?? 0) + indexPath.row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a Swiftier version of @Wain solution:

```
let rowNumber = Array(0..<indexPath.section).reduce(0) { $0 + tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: $1) } + indexPath.row
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say I implement the code below in `didSelectRowAt` / `didSelectItemAt` callbacks ...

### UITableView

```
var index: Int = indexPath.row
for i in 0..<indexPath.section {
    index += tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i)
}
```

### UICollectionView

```
var index: Int = indexPath.item
for i in 0..<indexPath.section {
    index += collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: i)
}
```

> *Example: 2 sections, 3 rows(items) each. Selected row(item) 1 in the section 1, `index` = 4*

Answer (score -4):

i dont know about the multiple sections but i can give you for the one section...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSInteger index=indexPath.row;
NSString *string=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)index];
}
```

from this you can get the row number and you can save it to the string....